# Flow INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE error

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, permissions, profile, error

I have an issue and I cannot figure it out what's the problem.
I have created a flow for changing shipping method and updating delivery address. When I run the flow with my system administrator profile everything goes as expected. When I try to run with a supervisior profile I have an issue when it tries to update some fields on OrderDeliveryGroupSummary Object and I have this error: : INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Unable to create/update fields: DeliverToCountry, DeliverToCity, DeliverToName, DeliverToState, DeliverToPostalCode, DeliverToStreet. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set

The problem is that I checked the object permission for this profile and it has the same permission as a system administrator. I gave access for everything this flow needs. These fields are not visible in the object because they are address type I believe, they are visibile only in Workbench, so I can not give access directly to these fields, but it's the same for System administrator and it works. How to solve this issue? Please help

Thank you!

Comment: The DeliverToStreet, DeliverToCity etc.. are subfields to the DeliverToAddress field. Are you positive that you have given your supervisor profile read/write access to DeliverToAddress?

Comment: Yes, it has the same access as System administrator for these fields. That's weird